# monotonic_buffer_resource and exception handling

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

The `monotonic_buffer_resource` works a bit like a stack that only supports push but not pop. Unfortunately I see no way howto revert to its previous state when catching an exception.

Even when handing your errors manually in the absence of exception handling, then you may still need to rollback your data to a previous state. How can you capture the state of this allocator resource and later revert to that state? If not possible, is there another resource I can use instead? Maybe a non standard one?

Otherwise, do I miss a reason why the `monotonic_buffer_resource` lacks any means to revert to a previous state? This should be exceptionally simple in my view, because this allocation resource skips calls to destructors anyhow.

Comment: It doesn't "skip destructors".  It's not an allocator's job to call the destructors, but they should still be called before the resource is destroyed.  It seems to be pretty difficult to design a checkpoint/restore mechanism for this that would be broadly useful in programs that respect RAII and simple enough to provide it by default in this resource.

Answer (score 0):

While this allocator is a "stack allocator", that *does not mean* the allocations it produces have a lifetime that is *in any way* bound by the actual execution stack of a thread. That is, just because you unwind the stack to some point does not mean that all allocations that were made within the now terminated part of the execution stack are now defunct.

You could have used those allocations as part of some object that now resides in some other object that survived the unwinding. You don't know; you *cannot know* because the allocator does not keep track of individual allocations. Indeed, not keeping track of individual allocations is *the entire point*.

Because the execution stack and the allocation stack are entirely separate, it is very dangerous to assume *anything* about the relationship between the two. If you are rigorous about how you use your monotonic allocations, then you *might* be able to do something like what you're talking about. But since there is no requirement that you do this (and it's very, *very* easy to get wrong), there's really no point.

Furthermore, it just violates the designed intent of the class. Again, the whole point is that it *doesn't* track individual allocations. You allocate a bunch of things, and then you throw them *all* away at the same time. That's the usage pattern. If your usage pattern is to allocate a bunch of things, throw some set of them away, then allocate more, then throw all of them away, that's a different usage pattern.

Or you just have two of them.

Comment: My use case is the following. I have a text and I am parsing it. The ast elements go into the allocator. But when I backtrack, I have to go back to some point and try a different path in the grammar. When I am done with the ast I throw the allocator resource away and I do not care about any destruction. At the moment I am using a deque for this purpose and it works fine but I do not like the fact that I am sometimes using the monotonic resource and sometimes the deque because I like to be as DRY as possible.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with using the stack allocator in the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "stack allocator". Allocator that uses the stack or one that has push and pop? the monotonic resource allocator has no pop and it does not allocate on the stack. My problem is that backtracking requires me to throw away any number of ast nodes at the end of the memory resource. In almost all cases I can ignore the problem and just take the penalty of consuming ten percent more memory. Unfortunately, I do not know what the maximum penalty can be as a result of backtracking because I do not know what grammars will be thrown at my compiler.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: "*Not sure what you mean with "stack allocator".*" `std::monotonic_buffer_resource` is an implementation of the concept of a "stack allocator". That is, the behavior it implements is what it means to be a "stack allocator". "*My problem is that backtracking requires me to throw away any number of ast nodes at the end of the memory resource.*" So the only problem is that your stack allocator may reserve more memory than is strictly needed.

Comment: @Bolas, No. Let me oversimplify. I need push and pop. The monotonic allocator has no pop. I removed the term "stack allocator" in my comment because it seems that most people seem to associate this term with an allocator using a buffer on the stack. They do not mean an allocator with stack behaviour. The monotonic allocator is neither of both interpretations as it does not use the stack and it also implements no pop. It seems I need to implement this allocator myself (if not, I am very sure you would have known). I do believe I have the terminology right but happy to learn if not.